# Drawing Coxeter graphs including arrows

Tags: graphics, graphs

In his paper "[Reflection centralizers in Coxeter groups](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1106.3822.pdf)" Allcock included (in Section 4) Coxeter graphs of the form below. I would also like to draw graphs like this in my Latex document but I do not know what package to use (and how to do that). (Usually you can download the .tex file from the paper on arxiv but somehow I didn't manage to do that.)

Has somebody a good suggestion?

[image: Graphs]

Comment: Do you need the thick curved arrows?

Comment: Yes, I do also need these.

Comment: Show us what did you try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tex source of mentioned paper is available from link https://arxiv.org/e-print/1106.3822v2 on webpage https://arxiv.org/format/1106.3822v2. You may need to append file extension `.tex` to the downloaded file.

The tex source shows that graph is drawn by `pstricks`:

```
The second example is $D_{n\geq6}$, which has $n-1$ arrow classes (starting at line 1401):
$$
% D7 diagram, with arrows.  origin at branch point, long arm to right
\raisebox{-.45\height}{%
\begin{pspicture*}(-100,-104)(408,104)
\solid{0}{0}
\solid{-50}{87}
\solid{-50}{-87}
\solid{100}{0}
\solid{200}{0}
\solid{300}{0}
\solid{400}{0}
\single{0}{0}{400}{0}
\single{0}{0}{-50}{87}
\single{0}{0}{-50}{-87}
\dbldown{100}{0}{$d$}
\dbldown{200}{0}{$e$}
\dbldown{300}{0}{$f$}
\Lthird{0}{0}{$a$}
\URthird{0}{0}{$b$}
\LRthird{0}{0}{$c$}
\end{pspicture*}
}%
\quad\to\quad
\raisebox{-.45\height}{%
\begin{pspicture}(-108,-104)(208,104)
%  D5
\solid{0}{0}
\solid{-50}{87}
\solid{-50}{-87}
\solid{100}{0}
\solid{200}{0}
\single{0}{0}{200}{0}
\single{0}{0}{-50}{87}
\single{0}{0}{-50}{-87}
\rput[r](-62,87){$b$}
\rput[r](-62,-87){$c$}
\rput[r](-15,0){$d$}
\rput[b](100,14){$e$}
\rput[b](200,14){$f$}
%  A1
\solid{-100}{0}
\rput[b](-100,14){$a$}
\end{pspicture}
}%
$$
```

[image]